# Parsing Json String to a Map

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON value like the following, and I needed to parse the pair values of data.

```
  {
    "columns" : [ "Book", "Publisher" ],
    "data" : [ [ "Book1", "Author1" ], [ "Book2", "Author2" ], [ "Book3", "Author3" ]]
  }
```

How should I use the org.json library to extract the values I needed, and put in data type like Map? I am using Java programming. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The dataset of "data" are query results, so we can't determined the value in the code. The columns Book and Publisher is known already, but the only thing we know about the dataset is they are a pair values.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: It's Java programming. I try to use the answer provided here, but I wasn't successful. The Json value is in a string format.

Comment: Seems like you have problems in converting String to JSONObject. Refer to my answer as it helps you with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't posted what you've attempted, I can't code for you. However here is something to get you started with json.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String jsondata = "{\"columns\" : [\"Book\", \"Publisher\" ],    \"data\" : [ [ \"Book1\", \"Author1\" ], [ \"Book2\", \"Author2\" ], [ \"Book3\", \"Author3\" ]]}";
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(jsondata);         
    JSONArray jsonval= (JSONArray)obj.get("data");
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i=0; i<jsonval.toArray().length; i++) {
        JSONArray datapair = (JSONArray)jsonval.get(i);
        String book = (String) datapair.get(0);
        String author = (String)datapair.get(1);
        map.put(book, author);
    }
}
```

Go through the documentation for syntax of inserting into maps

Comment: Thanks. But, what are the values given to the map, then? I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Added code to insert into map. Please remember to upvote and accept if it helps

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks. Now I realize, at least, I should have come up with inserting into the map. Thanks again for your kind help!

Comment: Glad to hear you're learning the approach rather than just fixing the errors in your code

Answer (score 0):

Here are the example for encoding and decoding of json using org.json lib:

Encoding:

```
 JSONArray list1 = new JSONArray();
  list1.add("foo");
  list1.add(new Integer(100));
  list1.add(new Double(1000.21));

  JSONArray list2 = new JSONArray();
  list2.add(new Boolean(true));
  list2.add(null);

  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  obj.put("name","foo");
  obj.put("num",new Integer(100));
  obj.put("balance",new Double(1000.21));
  obj.put("is_vip",new Boolean(true));
  obj.put("nickname",null);

  obj.put("list1", list1);
  obj.put("list2", list2);

  System.out.println(obj);
Result: {"balance":1000.21,"list2":[true,null],"num":100,"list1":["foo",100,1000.21],"nickname":null,"is_vip":true,"name":"foo"}
```

And Decoding:

Following example makes use of JSONObject and JSONArray where JSONObject is a java.util.Map and JSONArray is a java.util.List, so you can access them with standard operations of Map or List.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

class JsonDecodeDemo 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
      String s = "[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
      try{
         Object obj = parser.parse(s);
         JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
         System.out.println("The 2nd element of array");
         System.out.println(array.get(1));
         System.out.println();

         JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject)array.get(1);
         System.out.println("Field \"1\"");
         System.out.println(obj2.get("1"));    

         s = "{}";
         obj = parser.parse(s);
         System.out.println(obj);

         s= "[5,]";
         obj = parser.parse(s);
         System.out.println(obj);

         s= "[5,,2]";
         obj = parser.parse(s);
         System.out.println(obj);
      }catch(ParseException pe){
         System.out.println("position: " + pe.getPosition());
         System.out.println(pe);
      }
   }
}
While compile and executing above program, this will produce following result:

The 2nd element of array
{"1":{"2":{"3":{"4":[5,{"6":7}]}}}}

Field "1"
{"2":{"3":{"4":[5,{"6":7}]}}}
{}
[5]
[5,2]
```